# Can a NonWordpress Page on a Wordpress Based Site Cause Issues with Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I have a website built with Wordpress that has been having permalink issues. A few days ago, I had added a simple file, named qr.php, that I dropped in at the root level (where the wp-content and wp-upload folders reside). It has a script that redirect to pages outside of my website depending on what type of device the user is using. Basically, some one on a Apple device gets redirected to an itunes page, and droid user to the droid app store, etc.

Could this non Wordpress page be causing issues? I have had static or html pages in amonst my root level files before, and never had an issue. I feel like the redirects may change this.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Are you saying when you go to a WordPress page you are having issues or when you go to this qr.php you are having issues?

Comment: The qr.php seems to work fine. But I wasn't sure wether its presence in root folder among Worpress's core files is interfering with my site's permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the qr.php(cutom redirect file) in your wordpress site. You can use a plugin which will help to redirect the external links.

Some of the plugins which might help you to achieve your purpose are [Device Redirect - WordPress Phone &Tablet Redirect](http://codecanyon.net/item/device-redirect-wordpress-phone-tablet-redirect/8060392) , [RedirectPlus - Wordpress Mobile Redirect Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/redirectplus-wordpress-mobile-redirect-plugin/6696489).

See the screenshots, try demo and check whether it fits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

No, it dont cause any issue with permalink..
I am also using a wordpress website : abc.com and a php based software integrated to admin folder on root.. And I can access easily abc.com and abc.com/newfolder/abc.php